# Is there a fast and free code autocompletion system for Unreal Engine's C++ scripts in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, autocomplete, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm searching for a system which would:

- autocomplete code (when I print `UP...`, it suggests `UPROPERTY`; when I print `void Be...` it goes `void MainCharacter::BeginPlay() {}`...)
- provide some description for methods, variables, etc., as it's time-consuming to google them up. This also includes showing the arguments of functions, their types and their order.

I failed to find anything valuable, while Visual Studio's `Intelli Sense` is awfully slow. Printing a couple of letters stuns it for a while with this small animation in the bottom left corner: [image] ("Loading IntelliSense...")

---

*Something like that is shown:
[image]

Comment: I did not consider changing Visual Studio to anything. Although I've heard good responses on Rider, but it's not free and I cannot afford it, since I'm a beginner

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual Studios built-in IntelliSense tends to have a lot of issues with Unreal. I've had a lot of positive results with Visual Assist and Visual Studio 2019 so far, but [Visual Assist is a paid plugin](https://www.wholetomato.com/). Unfortunately, after using vanilla Visual Studio for years, I have not found a free solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and free and sort of Visual Studio would be VSCode + clangd.

See my unreal-clangd extension for VSCode https://github.com/boocs/unreal-clangd

It's for 5.1.0-5.2.0

One weird thing with clangd is you can't use the return value when typing code completion for a function. Just type the function name. If you type the return value first then code completion won't work.